# Is there any difference between these two javascript boolean expressions?

Tags: javascript

There are two ways I can check to see if a variable or property exists.

The first asserts that no falsy values are returned.

**1.**

```
var testVar;
if(!testVar){

    //use testVar becuase it exists 

}
```

The second asserts the two conditions explicitly.

**2.**

```
var testVar;

if(testVar !== undefined && testVar !== null){

    //use testVar becuase it exists 

}
```

With the goal of checking if the object/string/number/array exists, is there any difference between the two ?

Comment: Neither checks if the variable exists. Both check the value of the variable but perform different tests. Your question states the difference in the tests being performed, so I'm not sure what answer you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different. If you try to put `{}` or `1` or `true` or `"nyan cat"` [image: nyan!]... into `testVar`, then it returns `false` for `!testVar`:

```
var testVar = {};
if(!testVar){  //false
    //will not be executed, but testVar does exist
}
```

[image]

A better way to check if a variable exist:

```
typeof(randomVar); //undefined
typeof(window);    //object
```

---

### PS

```
var testVar;
if(!testVar){
    //...
}
```

This actually does not check if it exists. Try

```
var testVar = "something";
if(!testVar){              //false
    console.log("Exist.");
}
//nothing happens.
```

Comment: Similarly, consider what would happen if testVar had the value "true" in your first example or "null" in your second example. You may get some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Unexpected behavior is the expected behavior of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an object property exists by calling Object.hasOwnProperty(), but you cannot check whether a variable exists or not, as you cannot explicitly refer to the current stack frame.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong: you could check if a variable exists by accessing its value inside eval(), and catching any resulting exception, like this: eval("try { x; true } catch (e) { false }")

Answer (score 0):

**0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined and empty string ""** will be evaluated as false.

If testVar with value 0 is a valid condition, then 1st solution still treat it as "false". So, 2nd solution serves your case better.